# When the scene is loaded again start function is not getting called from the script in which I have applied singleton pattern

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

In `Game` scene I have an empty `GameObject` Circles to which a script named Circles is attached.
The script is:

```
public class Circles : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text text;
    LevelManager levelManager;
   public int score=0;
    int enemyNo;
  private void Awake()
    {
        int scorer = FindObjectsOfType<Circles>().Length;
        if (scorer > 1)
        {
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
      
    }
 void Start()
    {
        
        print("start");
        enemyNo = Random.Range(0, 4);
        Invoke("instantiator", 1.5f);
      
        text.text = score.ToString();
        levelManager = FindObjectOfType<LevelManager>();
        
    }
}
```

When the player loses he goes to `GameOver` scene where his score is displayed.
When the player presses play again button then he comes to `Game` scene again and the start function is not getting called.
When the player presses the play again button I want to destroy previously existing Circles `GameObject` and not the `GameObject` Circles which is present in the scene so that score is set to zero and the start function get called.
How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

i have figured out the solution for this question.
In the Circles script which is provided in the question I have added these lines of code:-

```
 void OnEnable()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnSceneLoaded;
    }

    private void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
    {
        // here you can use scene.buildIndex or scene.name to check which scene was loaded
        if (scene.name == "GameOver")
        {
            
            // Destroy the gameobject this script is attached to
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
```

And everything is working just as I wanted.